# Remove Datalist Dropdown Arrow in Chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

Chrome has apparently added a dropdown arrow to text inputs that reference a `<datalist>`. It's appearing in Chrome 34 (Canary) but not in the current stable build (Chrome 31).

It appears only when the text field is focused (see update) and is applied to both input types `text` and `search`.

It could be worse as far as native browser implementations go, but as you can see in the image, it conflicts with my design specs.

[image]

Does anyone know how to remove or replace this new feature?

```
<datalist id="list"><option value="foo"><option value="bar"></datalist>
<input type="text" list="list" name="field" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="off" placeholder="Jump To">
```

**Update:**

The arrow also appears when the field is hovered (not just focused) and unfortunately also has its own background color when the button itself is hovered:

[image]

Comment: I haven't looked, but this should be simple. Go into the dev console enable shadowdom and inspect the input element's shadow dom. Then you will see the arrow element including his pseudoclass it's propable a pseudoelement something like 'input::-webkit-list-arrow'.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by [alexander farkas](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/), here is the style rule to remove the arrow:

```
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: holy balls thank you so much for this. driving me crazy

Comment: I used this in combination with the :hover and :focus selectors to only show it when my users clicked in the input. Made it a little more obvious that it was optional with free text, and not a dropdown only control.

Comment: Warning this also impacts the html5 date input type. `[list]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator`  removes only datalists.

Comment: For IOS the selector is `::-webkit-list-button`

Comment: will not work in Chrome 91 and above without `!important` rule

Comment: finally adding !importantis working now ( chrome Version 97 )

Comment: Thank you @mustofa.id, without !important, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 30):

As others have mentioned `::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { display: none }` works at removing the arrow it would also impact the html5 datepicker on a `<input type="date">`,

#### To remove *just* removing the datalist input would be:

`[list]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
  }`

Comment: This should be the highest rated answer since it has the highest level of specificity, making it more robust for future form changes.

Comment: It should probably be noted that this is a Chrome-specific solution to a Chrome-specific problem, c.f: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693482/is-there-a-way-to-apply-a-css-style-on-html5-datalist-options

Comment: Can anyone suggest me a way to set this property using javascript(typescript to be more specific)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in 2021.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to Cantera. I didn't want to get rid of the black arrow entirely, just the gray square surrounding it.

```
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  background-color: inherit;
  }
```

Comment: Why not `background-color: transparent`?

Answer (score 8):

```
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Also removed the arrow for me and I found created a better clicking experience to still click where the arrow would be, you can even increase the the width and height of it > 1em and in the input maybe put a custom arrow as a background image, where the arrow would be.

Comment: Your solution is the one that worked for me, +1.

Comment: It appears "display: none" no longer works, this one does.

Comment: This is the way. The other way still shows the arrow when hovering over the input

Answer (score 3):

```
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

It's work for me; (use display:0 not work on chorme)

Answer (score 2):

```
datalist::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none; 
    opacity: 0;
}
```

It is okay but this css code will hide any calander on page.
Like I'm using datepicker calender and this will also hide the controls including datalist and datetime picker.

Answer (score 1):

```css
input[type="text"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator,
input[type="email"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator, 
input[type="search"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<input list="someList" placeholder="show arrow">
<input type="text" list="someList" placeholder="no arrow">

<datalist id="someList">
  <option value="option 1">
  <option value="option 2">
</datalist>
```

Answer (score -2):

Set the ***list*** option of parent ***input*** to be empty,   `<input list="" ... />` , eg :

```
<input
  list=""
  name="option"
  id="input"
  autocomplete="off"
>

<datalist id="datalist">
  <option>Carrots</option>
  <option>Peas</option>
  <option>Beans</option>
</datalist>
```

see mdn [customizing_datalist_styles example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist#customizing_datalist_styles)

Comment: This disconnects the datalist from the input, so it no longer functions. The MDN example manually enables the datalist using JavaScript to avoid the input from getting "datalist attached" styles... but that's at a loss of functionality and is a bad idea (e.g. the user can no longer navigate the datalist with the keyboard).

Answer (score -4):

try `-webkit-appearance: none` that should remove the default styles

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't remove the arrow; same goes for `appearance: none`