# remove arrow in chrome for input with attribute "list"

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

I have this code:

```
<input list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Google Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

In Chrome I get the little black down arrow in right corner

[image: field with arrow]

Is there any way to remove or hide that?

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarhov/S4w5B/12)**

**UPDATE:**

I know that I can wrap it, and then close it with psuedo-element as show in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S4w5B/9/)

But I need another solution for that, is there any other way?

Comment: What version of Chrome? I'm not getting it on Chrome 34. ([Screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/XVjnb5FLm9v))

Comment: mine is 34 too, but in focus or hover I get it

Comment: sorry, wrong link was in, here is the correct one

http://jsfiddle.net/sarhov/S4w5B/12/

Comment: @jsve I am planning to put there the search icon



here is the screenshot

http://goo.gl/OeKwgm

Comment: @sarhov http://jsfiddle.net/S4w5B/14/

Comment: @null why don't you add that as an answer. It seems to work.

Comment: @null

oh, I have just noticed your comment, that's work like charm,

add that as answer, your version is working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Datalist Dropdown Arrow in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937475/remove-datalist-dropdown-arrow-in-chrome)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The  following will work:

```
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}
```

**[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/S4w5B/14/)**

Comment: Good find!. Why an earth do they make things so complex.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this today.
In Chrome 97 i needed to add an important tag to make it work

```
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pg0et59w/3/