# Remove iOS datalist input arrow

Tags: css, ios, safari, html-datalist

Safari on iOS add a blue arrow when using a `datalist` with an `input` on a website, like this :

[image]

I found some thread to remove the same arrow for Chrome like this one : [Remove Datalist Dropdown Arrow in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937475/remove-datalist-dropdown-arrow-in-chrome) and it works but not for iOS and I can't find a way to hide it.

```html
<input type="text" list="datalist">
<datalist id="datalist">
    <option>Carrots</option>
    <option>Peas</option>
    <option>Beans</option>
</datalist>
```

I created a basic demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/hudrfgw2/4/

Answer (score 0):

`arrow` will be use in safari, so it can be hide but can't remove.

the best solution is:

```
input[list]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator,
input[list]::-webkit-list-button {
    opacity: 0 !important
}
```