# How to disable the arrow mark of the textbox

Tags: html, html-datalist

I will assign the datalist to the text box, it is working but I want to remove the right side arrow mark.

```
<input type="text" list="categoryList" name="category">

<datalist id="categoryList">
    <option value="entertainment">
    <option value="education">
    <option value="photography">
    <option value="sports">
</datalist>
```

[image]

[http://jsfiddle.net/utrfectL](http://jsfiddle.net/utrfectL/)

Comment: it's as limited as, or more than, the `select` element, so I don't think you can.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693482/is-there-a-way-to-apply-a-css-style-on-html5-datalist-options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}
```

CSS seems to do it.

From tests it looks like the arrow is only added by webkit browsers (does not appear either way in Firefox or IE) so that should be all you have to do.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utrfectL/1/)

Comment: That will only work for Chrome and Safari (webkit)
However, the OP's issue doesnt seem to be present in FFox.

Comment: It appears as though the arrow only appears for webkit browsers anyway.

Comment: I stand corrected.  At least webkit was nice enough to allow overriding this.