# Putting CSS to <datalist>

Tags: html, css, html-datalist

so right now i have a simple datalist drop down menu and i want to change the CSS of it so that the style matches with the rest of the fields on the website. However i am a web design noob and i am kind of confused as to get this process done.

refer to:
http://jsfiddle.net/ryax5L29/20/

```
<input list="ServiceCity">
<datalist id="ServiceCity" name="ServiceCity"class = "atl_services">
            <option value "" disabled selected>Select City/County</option>
            .......other values
        </datalist>
```

This is the CSS i want to use

```
input{
    padding: 7px;
    outline: none;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px
    width: 88.5%;
    border: 1px solid GREY;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px GREY;
    }
```

I have the CSS in there as well, imo it will be easiest to inline the CSS but if someone can guide me through that it would be great thanks!

Comment: styling a datalist is up to the browser, there are very few styling options for the list. can you use jquery on your site ? I suspect the reason for the downvote is because styling a datalist has been asked on here a million times

Comment: aw so i guess i cant just inline a datalist style?

Comment: you can only style the input box and a few options for the opt list, color etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to apply a CSS style on HTML5 datalist options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693482/is-there-a-way-to-apply-a-css-style-on-html5-datalist-options)

Answer (score 19):

[Per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Styling_HTML_forms):

> Some elements simply can't be styled using CSS. These include all advanced user interface widgets such as range, color, or date controls as well as all the dropdown widgets, including `<select>`, `<option>`, `<optgroup>` and `<datalist>` elements. The file picker widget is also known not to be stylable at all. The new `<progress>` and `<meter>` elements also fall in this category.

Comment: This is the most sad answer for designers.

Comment: This should be the proper answer to this question and all its duplicates

Answer (score 0):

I have given the name attribute to the list Input as shown below and also added the css Input with a name which works perfectly.

```
<input list="ServiceCity" name="service-city">
<datalist id="ServiceCity" name="ServiceCity"class = "atl_services">
            <option value "" disabled selected>Select City/County</option>
            .......other values
        </datalist>
```

CSS Code as follow:

```
input[name="service-city"] {
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: This is styling the input, though, not the datalist.