# Show first 10 results, hide the rest?

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I have a php and SQL code I use to extract data into a `datalist` HTML with `input`.

The code is fairly generic and should be know to everyone:

```
<datalist id="FindPlace">
 <option hidden></option>
 <?php
   $sql = "SELECT IDPlace, Place_Name, FKCity FROM Places WHERE Place_Name <> '' ORDER BY Place_Name";

   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<option>" . $row["Place_Name"] . "</option>";
     }
    }
  ?>
</datalist>
```

I've tried to use `LIMIT`, but it hides every other result, where in I need to have them all usable, just not showing everything when I click on the `input`but only like first 10 options.

I also tried to insert something like `$counter` in php code between `while`and `echo`like this:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT IDPlace, Place_Name, FKCity FROM Places WHERE Place_Name <> '' 
ORDER BY Place_Name";
$counter = 10;

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  if ($row < $counter) {
   echo "<option>" . $row["Place_Name"] . "</option>";
  }
  else {
   break;
  }
 }
}
?>
```

And it didn't work. I don't really know how to use JQuery so it would be preferable to not use it, maybe there's a command I don't know, or some trick?

Comment: You might want to think of a next/prev system, because if you have a lot of places, you will get a slow page, for only 10 items (visitors dont care about hidden items)

Comment: The obvious answer would be to use css, but there doesn't appear to be a way to style this.  Suggestion is to drop datalist and use an auto-complete plugin.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693482/is-there-a-way-to-apply-a-css-style-on-html5-datalist-options

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this using a css. Try something like below code. This is something relevant fiddle check this: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/PY5Fe/198/)

```css
 
.wrapper option:nth-child(n+11){
  background-color: gold;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    
    <option>Container #1</option>
    <option>Container #2</option>
    <option>Container #3</option>
    <option>Container #4</option>
    <option>Container #5</option>
    <option>Container #6</option>
    <option>Container #7</option>
    <option>Container #8</option>
    <option>Container #9</option>
    <option>Container #10</option>
    <option>Container #11</option>
    <option>Container #12</option>
    
</div>
```

Comment: The css doesn't work. Shows me all options instead of first 10.

Comment: Beautiful ... wasn't aware of that possibility

Comment: @Zabusy, you want something like this?

Comment: @chiragsatapara Yeah, the idea is something like that, though the hidden contrainers should still be accessible if I write their name in `datalist` and `input`

Comment: Your snippet doesn't use a `datalist`.  You can't use css on a datalist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $i=0;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $i++;
        if ($i<=10) {
            echo "<option>" . $row["Place_Name"] . "</option>";
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried. Maybe the problem is something else? Now in my `input` it doesn't show anything, as the case with my second example.