# Styling the background of a datalist

Tags: html, css

I am using a datalist to display some options, but I need  to set the background of the options to white. I've tried playing around with the background-colour element, but no matter what I do the options always have a black background.

```css
datalist {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
    <body>
        <input
          list="datalist"
          name="option"
          id="input"
          autocomplete="off"
        >

        <datalist id="datalist">
          <option>Carrots</option>
          <option>Brocolli</option>
          <option>Lettuce</option>
        </datalist>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `datalist` can't really be styled since the browser decides on how that element is displayed. You'd have to craft your own datalist with stylable HTML elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datalist` elements unfortunately cannot be styled directly. They receive their style by the current browser. See [Is there a way to apply a CSS style on HTML5 datalist options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693482/is-there-a-way-to-apply-a-css-style-on-html5-datalist-options)

Comment: I was afraid this was going to be the case. How annoying. 
Thank you anyway.