# css style for datalist object

Tags: html, css

I have this simple fatalist:

```
<input list="myList" />
<datalist id="myList">
   <option>Option 1</option>
   <option>Option 2</option>
</datalist>
```

and I would like to change the style with css:
For example: set the cursor as pointer on option:hover

I tried this:

```
#myList > option:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

But this has no effect.
Any idea? :)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693482/is-there-a-way-to-apply-a-css-style-on-html5-datalist-options