# Clickable options inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make the option element tags inside a div clickable. More like a select tag. You might think, why I cannot use a select element. In my case, I need a search bar with a menu. Therefore I have used an input. I tried it in the following way. Seems like the value attribute isn't assignable and it is not clickable. Does anyone have any idea about this?

html:

```
<input id="searchInput" list="searchList" type="text" placeholder="Search.." onkeyup="filterFunction()">
<div id="searchList" class="dropdown-content">
</div>
```

javascript:

```
    function fillList(elementIdentifier, data) {
        const list = document.querySelector(elementIdentifier);
        
        data.errorMessages.forEach(element => {
            
            const option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = element.MessageId;
            option.label = element.namespace + ": " + element.message;

            list.appendChild(option);
        });
    }

    function filterFunction() {
                    
                    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
                    input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
                    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                    div = document.getElementById("searchList");
                    a = div.getElementsByTagName("option");
                    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                        txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
                        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                            a[i].style.display = "";
                        } else {
                            a[i].style.display = "none";
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great answer by @connexo
Another way is to use event bubbling and add event listener to the div itself and then you can get the target to check which option was clicked.

```js
function fillList(elementIdentifier) {
  const list = document.querySelector(elementIdentifier);

  var data = {
    errorMessages: [{
        "MessageId": "x",
        "namespace": "x",
        "message": "Stack"
      },
      {
        "MessageId": "y",
        "namespace": "y",
        "message": "Overflow"
      }
    ]
  };

  data.errorMessages.forEach(element => {

    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = element.MessageId;
    option.label = element.namespace + ": " + element.message;

    list.appendChild(option);
  });
}

fillList("#searchList")

var div = document.getElementById("searchList");

div.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
});

function filterFunction() {

  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

  a = div.getElementsByTagName("option");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].label;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="searchInput" list="searchList" type="text" placeholder="Search.." onkeyup="filterFunction()">
<div id="searchList" class="dropdown-content">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. How I can get the clicked value into the input field?

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel?

HTML has you covered already. Use a `datalist`, which already comes with matching suggestions that are clickable:

```js
const s = document.getElementById('searchCountries');

const countries = ['USA', 'UK', 'Germany', 'India', 'Finland', 'Canada'];
for (const country of countries) {
  const o = document.createElement('option');
  o.value = country;
  s.append(o);
}
```

```html
<input type="search" list="searchCountries" />
<datalist id="searchCountries"></datalist>
```

Comment: Could this be styled with custom CSS? Just a question

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I don't have the highest hopes for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693482/is-there-a-way-to-apply-a-css-style-on-html5-datalist-options and here's an attempt: https://dev.to/siddev/customise-datalist-45p0

Comment: @connexo Thanks. But I cannot use that since when I tried it inside the vscode extension, it detaches the datalist from the search bar. Tried to fix it. It didn't work. That's why I tried to implement it in this way