# how to Style a list input

Tags: html, css, input, drop-down-menu, textbox

I was looking for an auto-completing text field when I stumbled upon lists.

```
<label>Bad Habit
  <input list="badhabits" id="habits" name="habit"/>
</label>
<datalist id="badhabits"> 
  <option value="alcaholics">
  <option value="smoking">
</datalist>
```

They work but I'd like to know how to style them, like you can with other inputs (buttons etc). I've tried giving it an `id` and doing it that way

```
#habits{
    padding:5px;
    border:2px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I aslo tried doing

```
[type=list] {
    padding:5px;
    border:2px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

But this also did not work. So does anyone know how to style a list?

Comment: sorry forgot the list code   `<label>Bad Habit
  <input list="badhabits" id=""habits" name="habit" /></label>
  <datalist id="badhabits">
  <option value="alcaholics">
  <option value="smoking">
  </datalist><p/ >`

Answer (score 2):

There have been other discussions on how to style the options of the datalist element as they appear in the input element's dropdown. Currently I don't believe there is a way to do it - it is up to the browser on how to interpret the style of these elements.

Duplicate of [Is it possible to style the drop-down suggestions when using html5 datalist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062414/is-it-possible-to-style-the-drop-down-suggestions-when-using-html5-datalist)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried as per below and it works for me perfectly.

```
<label>Bad Habit
  <input list="badhabits" id="habits" name="habit"/>
</label>
<datalist id="badhabits"> 
  <option value="alcaholics">
  <option value="smoking">
</datalist>
```

CSS Code as follow:

```
input[name="habit"] {
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I think that, now, this is the best solution:

```
[list="badhabits"] {
    padding:5px;
    border:2px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
[type=list] {
padding:5px;
border:2px solid #ccc;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

You should do this:

```
[list="badhabits"] {
padding:5px;
border:2px solid #ccc;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I guess this is what you are looking for

```css
select {
   border: solid 1px blue; 
   font-weight: bold; 
}
option { 
   background-color:yellow; 
   color: red;
   font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="">aaa</option>
    <option value="">aaa</option>
    <option value="">aaa</option>
    <option value="">aaa</option>
</select>
```

Comment: sort of except how would I make this work in a database cuase I get this error 
Notice: Undefined index: habit in C:\xampp\htdocs\Breakr\create-account.php on line 84

Comment: This isn't a question about the <select> element!